# Select all visible rows and columns of Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a dynamic excel sheet, where some rows and columns are hidden. I can't tell which rows and which columns are hidden as they keep changing. I need to extract all visible data and create a list of rows. 
This is what I have as of now:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
string cellValue = string.Empty;
string fileName = @"C:\Source\filename.xlsx";
CorpData datatest = new CorpData();
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, true, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks[1].Sheets["Sheet1"];

    Excel.Range usedRrange = excelWorkSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);
    int count = usedRrange.Count;
    int rowCount = usedRrange.Count / usedRrange.Columns.Count;

    foreach (Excel.Range area in usedRrange.Areas)
    {
        foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
        {
            string[] rowData = new String[7];
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                Excel.Range rowRange = excelWorkSheet.Cells[row.Row, j + 1];
                if (rowRange.Value2 != null)
                {
                    rowData[j] = rowRange.Value2.ToString();
                }

             }
             datatest.DataList.Add(new DataItem(rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[2], rowData[3], rowData[4], rowData[5], rowData[6]));
        }
    }
}
```

Issue here is that I am able to get rid of all hidden rows, but since I parse through the main excel for all columns, I am still getting hidden column values. If somebody can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I quickly did a google search and came up with the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3a3d9c1-7f2d-45de-bf90-c664fbfe6068/how-to-programmatically-hide-a-column-on-the-excel?forum=vsto) - "Worksheet.get_Range("C:C", missing).EntireColumn.Hidden = true"